# I'm fascinated by 'death': what would Dogen say?

Tags: zen, death, dogen

I'm fascinated by 'death': what would Dogen say? What about Rinzai zen?

I don't have any questions about it, but I'm sure there's answers I haven't contemplated at all.

Quotes would be necessary.

Comment: just for clarity: imvho when we die birth is over, and both our small and buddha self are aligned to whatever extent. that's probably a heresy, but i'm here to learn new things!

Comment: Possibly you could add some content to your question by reading these links: link 1: https://tricycle.org/magazine/birth-and-death/  
                                  
link 2:  https://tricycle.org/trikedaily/fundamentals-of-dogens-thoughts/

Comment: thanks @Dhammadhatu a worthy starting point!!

Answer (score 2):

> Dogen quotes from Goodreads on the internet

Life and death are of supreme importance. Time swiftly passes by and opportunity is lost. Each of us should strive to awaken. Awaken! Take heed, do not squander your life.

This dew-like life will fade away; avoid involvement in superfluous things.

There is a simple way to become buddha: When you refrain from unwholesome actions, are not attached to birth and death, and are compassionate toward all sentient beings, respectful to seniors and kind to juniors, not excluding or desiring anything, with no designing thoughts or worries, you will be called a buddha. Do not seek anything else.

One must be deeply aware of the impermanence of the world.

It's too late to be ready.